# Searching Persian characters and words in SQL server with different encoding

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, farsi

I have a text file that contains Persian words and is saved using ANSI encoding. When I try to read the Persian words from the text file, I get some characters like '?'. To solve the problem, I changed the file encoding to UTF8 and re-wrote the text file. Here's the method for changing file encoding:

```
    public void Convert2UTF8(string filePath)
    {
        //first, read the text file with "ANSI" endocing
        StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default);
        string fileContent = fileStream.ReadToEnd();
        fileStream.Close();
        //Now change the file encoding and replace it with the UTF8
        StreamWriter utf8Writer = new StreamWriter(filePath.Replace(".txt", ".txt"), false, Encoding.UTF8);
        utf8Writer.Write(fileContent);
        utf8Writer.Close();
    }
```

Now the first problem is solved; However, there is another issue here: every time that I want to search a Persian word from the SQL server database table, the result is null while the record **does** exist in the database table.

What's the solution to find my Persian words that exist in the table? The code that I currently use is simply like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[WordDirectory] 
WHERE Word = N'کلمه'
```

`Word` is the field that Persian words are saved in. The type of the field is `NVARCHAR`. My SQL server version is 2012.
Should I change the collation?

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Field NVARCHAR(4000) COLLATE Frisian_100_CI_AI)

INSERT INTO @Table (Field) VALUES
(N'همهٔ افراد بش'),
(N'می‌آیند و حیثیت '),
(N'ميشه آهسته تر صحبت کنيد؟'),
(N'روح'),
(N' رفتار')   

SELECT * FROM @Table
WHERE Field LIKE N'%آهسته%'
```

The both Queries return the same result

```
RESULT Set:  ميشه آهسته تر صحبت کنيد؟
```

You have to make sure that when you are inserting the values you prefix then witn `N` thats to tell sql server there can be unicode character in the passed string. Same is true when you are searching for them strings in Select statement.

Comment: I fully am familiar with the usage of N and inserting Persian characters into the database. I should have mentioned in the question that I used SqlBulkCopy because I had over 9 million records to insert. Is there something in SqlBulkCopy to make it clear that the type of the field in sql table is NVARCHAR?

Comment: Try using the Like Predicate with `%` see what you get then

Comment: I tried all kinds of `Like` with using `%` and the result is still nothing! I can upload the minimized version of the database if you want to try by yourself!

Comment: @Pedram Try using a Farsi Collation see my update. it works fine here.

Comment: by changing the Collation, now it works for the case that you mentioned. but for example for the case `SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE FIELD LIKE N'آهسته'` or `SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE FIELD = N'آهسته'` it does not return any result. I want to find the exact match not the fields that contain the word.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have problem with Persian and Arabic versions of the 'ي' and 'ك' during search. These characters even look the same, have different Unicode numbers:

```
select NCHAR(1740),  -- Persian ى
       NCHAR(1610),  -- Arabic ي
       NCHAR(1705), -- Persian ك
       NCHAR(1603) -- Arabic ك
```

more info: http://www.dotnettips.info/post/90

Comment: It may also need to use `like` operator.

Comment: @afsharm: I`ve already tried `like` too. but it has still the problem.

Comment: @VahidN: unfortunately it`s not for the case you`ve mentioned. for example, take a look at the picture at this address and you get what I`m saying: http://www.4shared.com/photo/LQd-2vOAba/1__1_.html

Comment: @VahidN tnx for great scrip but it throw error if we have duplicate value :Cannot insert duplicate key row in object